# Mat-icons not working at Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, iis, angular-material, icons, angular7

I have a problem with displaying mat-icons in my asp.net-mvc app with front-end based on Angular 7.

The problem is really weird because when I'm trying to open my app at localhost using Internet Explorer it works correctly. But  when I deploy it to the IIS server it behaves different than at localhost. Actually there is only one difference between them. Mat-icons (I don't know about others because I didn't try it yet), aren't displayed by browser, and there is only a huge gap, much bigger than icons size in it's place.

Maybe helpful information is, that I noticed Explorer tries to open app in version 7 instead of default 11 so I added
`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11">`. IE behaves really weird 
when I try to open app deployed to the server, it's hard to describe but for example.

I was getting in developers console I had errors like:

> Error: Object doesn't support property or method bind

Of course problem doesn't exist for another browsers (even Edge). Everything works correctly at localhost and server as well.
Do you have any idea what is the problem? It looks the reason is not in the code because I deployed branch from 2 months ago and it worked the same, and I'm almost sure it worked fine at january. Maybe it's something about server and IIS but I didn't change anything there so I have no idea what happened to app.

Comment: Problems like this are usually caused by IE security settings. You can try going into Settings > Internet Options > Security and ensure protected mode is off and security level is low.

Comment: It would also be helpful if you detail how you import material icons

Comment: I'm not 100% sure right now, but I think it's included to project by:                           
                                                                                                                         
     import { AppMaterialsModule } from '../app-materials-module/app-materials.module';

Comment: Changing Settings didn't help. It wouldn't make any sense if it works correctly on one tab (localhost) and wrong at second from IIS server.

Comment: Try to add the following code in the idex.html. "<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">". If still not working, you can try to re-deploy the app to the server.